# Why does my INDEX MATCH formula not work on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I am having some issues with extracting the correct data to the "Battery Logs" Sheet from "FC" Sheet. I am trying to copy the data from the column range C2:D in "FC" Sheet to column range D2:E in "Battery Logs" Sheet under certain requirements.

The requirements are that the "Battery Number" and the "Date of Charging" under the "Battery Logs" Sheet should match with the "Battery Number" and the "Date" under the "FC" Sheet.

I tried using this INDEX MATCH formula:

```
=arrayformula(INDEX(FC!C2:D, MATCH( (A2=FC!A:A) * (B2=FC!B:B), 0)))
```

And the end result in the Battery Logs does not even match the requirements.

The formula is in D2:E2 under the "Battery Logs".

For the desired output, I would want D2:E in "Battery Logs" to follow and match with C2:D in "FC" to match the said requirements.

Any idea how I could get this correct data output displayed in my “Battery Logs” sheet?

Will really appreciate if any kind souls could help me out with this thanks!

The link to my Google Sheets is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y6XiuxwQsswLEfow3cU8XPHfBEC8USFKA7kP2tXoUbQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: The copies of my sheets are inside my post above. As for the desired output, I would want E2:F in "Battery Logs" to follow and match with D2:E in "FC" to match the said requirements.

Comment: You have shared *images*, not links to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of your spreadsheet, or to a representative sample of your spreadsheet). Formulas are written around specific data, and right now, we don't have access to the data without the volunteers here first needing to hand-enter the data in your images themselves. If you'd like help, please share a link to the spreadsheet(s) shown in your images.

Comment: I have edited my post accordingly. Have included the link to my Google Sheets thanks for the reply!